# VSCode terminal task not using zsh profile

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, nvm

I'm trying to run a task on window load in VSCode where a terminal opens and `nvm use && yarn dev` is run by default. However, running this shell tasks seems to not load my zsh profile.

The output I get from running my task is:

```
The terminal process "zsh '-c', 'nvm use && yarn dev'" terminated with exit code: 127.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

But if I then manually start a new terminal and run the same command (ie: by pressing plus, opening a new integrated terminal), it will work as intended.

Suspecting that VSCode isn't loading my profile for some reason, I tried adding the following to my task, it resulted in the error `/bin/zsh: can't open input file: nvm use && yarn dev The terminal process "zsh '-l', 'nvm use && yarn dev'" terminated with exit code: 127.`.

```json
// in dev task
"options": {
  "shell": {
    "executable": "zsh",
    "args": ["-l"]
  }
},
```

#### .vscode/tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "presentation": {
      "echo": false,
      "reveal": "always",
      "focus": false,
      "panel": "dedicated",
      "showReuseMessage": true
    },
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Create terminals",
        "dependsOn": [
          "Dev",
        ],
        // Mark as the default build task so cmd/ctrl+shift+b will create them
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        // Try start the task on folder open
        "runOptions": {
          "runOn": "folderOpen"
        }
      },
      {
        "label": "Dev",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": 
          ["nvm use && yarn dev"],
        "isBackground": true,
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "presentation": {
          "group": "dev-group"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem and none of the answers resolve this.
Opened a bug for this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143061

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me*:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "/bin/zsh",
        "args": ["-l", "-i"]
    }
},
```

**(add to your `settings.json`)*

[github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143061](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143061)

**Update-**
For default shell provide the below setting-

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Although `"args": ["-l", "-i"]` is set, what is actually executed is `/bin/zsh '-l', '-i', '-c'`。According to Tim's answer below, `-c` means not to start the shell as non-login, non-interactive, so the `~/.zshrc` configuration cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 6):

You may need to add an automation profile as well

```
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
      "path": "/bin/zsh -l",
      "args": ["-l"]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx": {
    "path": "/bin/zsh"
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

try adding this to your `settings.json`

```json
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        [...]
        "zsh": {
            "path": "/bin/zsh -l",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        },
        [...]
  },
```

Note that the important part is

```json
    "path": "/bin/zsh -l",
```

I had the same problem and I found that for some reason VScode does not take into consideration the `-l` flag passed in `args`. So you can just include it with `path`.

If you do not have `terminal.integrated.profiles.osx` in your settings, you can copy it from the default settings (open the Command Palette and search for 'default settings').

I did not need to do this, but you can make sure that zsh is the default terminal profile for VScode by setting `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx` to `zsh`

Comment: My integrated terminal works fine normally, and this did not help the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

via GUI you can do the following

Press `command` + `,` and search for `terminal.integrated.showExitAlert` than unselect thick like below >
[image]

I hope that will not get minus points here...

Answer (score 2):

Try running `echo $SHELL` from VSCode's integrated terminal. If you're on a Mac or Linux machine, you can compare that output to the output from the terminal app (outside VSCode). It's possible your default shell in VSCode is set incorrectly or using a copy of zsh at another location. If so, set VSCode's default shell through the command palette (`Terminal: Select Default Shell`).

Also check out your shell's default profile (`Terminal: Select Default Profile`) from the command palette and make sure it's set to `zsh -l`... using the `-c` argument (non-login non-interactive) will prevent `~/.zshrc` from being executed, which sounds like what's going on here given your error output.

Finally, confirm your profile is located correctly (at `~/.zshrc`) and that both nvm and yarn `PATH`s are exported. Alternatively, if you're trying to reference yarn locally (if for some reason you only installed it locally), you'll need to run yarn via npx...

Comment: My default shell works fine (via the integrated terminal). The only issue is when I'm trying to run the shell automatically from a VSCode task.

Comment: Although `"args": ["-l", "-i"]` is set, what is actually executed is `/bin/zsh '-l', '-i', '-c'`. Do you know why?