# Tasks: env: php: No such file or directory

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have updated to Mac OS Monterrey and the extension Better PHPUnit stopped working. This extension runs vscode tasks to make the output in colors, etc.

The error I got when running the tasks is `env: php: No such file or directory`. If I run the command in the console without using the task, all runs as it should, without any issues.

So investigating and trying to isolate the problem, I have created a task inside VSCODE and seems that the terminal used for tasks is picking up some other `$PATH` so `php` is not found.

I have installed PHP using Homebrew. I can execute scripts without any issue BUT when I run `echo $PATH` inside a task the output is different that when I run the same command in an integrated terminal.

The task I'm using to test is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo $PATH",
            "group": "test",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The output:

```
> Executing task: echo $PATH <

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

And if I run the command `echo $PATH` in an integrated terminal I get:

```
/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Users/xxx/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "the extension Better PHPUnit stopped working" - what does that mean? Is there any error message given? If VSCode uses a diffent path setting, why not correct that?

Comment: @NicoHaase the extension has some tasks to execute the tests with keyboard keys, when using those tasks the error I see in console is `env: php: No such file or directory`. But if I execute the command myself from the vscode console they work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered `env: php: No such file or directory` issue after updating brew on my mac and I followed these steps below to resolve it

Step 1:

I ran `which php` on my terminal to get the path to php and then opened vscode settings
(Code -> Preferences ->  Settings)

Step 2:

Click  PHPUnit configuration under User and add the copied path to the input box  labeled `Phpunit: PHP`
(mine happened to be blank)

In your case, you can click `Edit in settings.json` under `Extensions > PHP > Validate : Executable Path` and paste the copied php path to `php.validate.executablePath`

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work on my end :( vscode sees the `php.validate.executablePath` but when executing the task the console launched doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue off and on with macOS. I was able to figure this out with the help of [this comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70942924/4990632)

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "/bin/zsh -l",
        "args": []
    },
}
```

Unfortunately not solving my issue with a specific extension, but I could make some tasks now.